# How to get all the attributes in python for a class that inherits from a named_tuple

Tags: python, inheritance, namedtuple

I have a python class that I inherit from a named tuple. I add another attribute to it's instance

```
from collections import namedtuple
class Test(namedtuple("Test", ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))):
     pass
T = Test(1,2,3,4,5)
T.list = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

So T has 6 attributes: a,b,c,d,e,list. Is there any way to print all the attributes using one command? "T.__dict" gives me just "list" attribute. "T.__fields" gives me all the namedtuple fields.

I don't think I fully understand what inheriting from namedtuple does.

Comment: If you want to control the fields yourself, why not just inherit from `tuple` directly?

Comment: `namedtuple` uses [__slots__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `dir(T)` command will print all the attributes (including builtin, class attributes) of T.

```
from collections import namedtuple
class Test(namedtuple("Test", ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))):
     pass
T = Test(1,2,3,4,5)
T.list = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print dir(T)
```

output:

> > ['**add**', '**class**', '**contains**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**', '**getnewargs**', '**getslice**', '**getstate**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**iter**', '**le**', '**len**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**mul**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**rmul**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**slots**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '_asdict', '_fields', '_make', '_replace', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'count', 'd', 'e', 'index', 'list']